# How to call super class method within class

Tags: ruby, class

How can I call super class method within class like:

```
class A  
  def foo  
    puts "lol"  
  end  
end

class B < A  
  foo  
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to call an instance method from within the context of a class. This is not valid.

What would work:

```
class A  
  def self.foo  
    puts "lol"  
  end  
end

class B < A  
  foo
end
```